# Apache beam python looking up value in other collection

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am trying to lookup a value in a seperate big query table, i need to lookup the link_url in table one using the url in table 2. From table 1 i need just the link_id

table 1

| link_id | link_url |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | https://link1.com |
| id2 | https://link2.com |
| id3 | https://link3.com |

table 2

| url | app |
| --- | --- |
| https://link1.com | App1 |
| https://link2.com | App2 |
| https://link3.com | App3 |
| https://link4.com | App4 |

desired output:

| link_id | link_url | app |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | https://link1.com | App1 |
| id2 | https://link2.com | App2 |
| id3 | https://link3.com | App3 |
| null | https://link4.com | App4 |

What i have

```
import logging
import apache_beam as beam

def use_side_input(main, side_input):

   return side_input[main]

def run():
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        links = p | 'ReadLinks' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table="table1", gcs_location="gs://bucket/tmp/")

        linkviews = p | 'LinkViews' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table="table2", gcs_location="gs://bucket/tmp/")

        out | "use side input" >> beam.Map(use_side_input, side_input=beam.pvalue.AsDict(links))
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

I know i should be using side inputs but i have no clue how to continue

Comment: In the side input function I’m not sure how to do the matching of the url and adding new columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave the solution here for anyone else

```
def add_link(main, side_input):
    url = main["url"]

    result = side_input.get(url)

    main["link_id"] = None
    if result:
        main["link_id"] = result[0]

    return main


def link_key(event):
    url = event["link_url"]

    return url, [event["link_id"]]

links_keys = links | 'AddLinkKey' >> beam.Map(
            link_key)

#

final = (out | "AddLink" >> beam.Map(add_link, side_input=beam.pvalue.AsDict(link_keys)))
```